# If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ are positive integers such that $abcde=a+b+c+d+e$, then what is the maximum value of $e$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, optimization, maxima-minima

> If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ are positive integers such that $abcde=a+b+c+d+e$, then what is the maximum value of $e$?
>
> The answer is $5$.

What I tried:

Let $a\leq b \leq c \leq d \leq e$. Then 
$$abcde \leq 5e \quad\Rightarrow\quad abcd \leq 5$$

For the maximum value of $e$, here $a=b=c=1$ and $d=5$.

So $$e=\frac{a+b+c+d}{abcd-1}=\frac{8}{4}=2$$
But this is not the answer.

How do I solve it? Help me, please.

Comment: Well, if $abcd\leq5$ and $a\leq b\leq c\leq d$ are positive integers, there are only a very limited number of possibilities for what $a,b,c,d$ are. Why not just check them all one by one? And remember that it's not necessarily the maximal possible value of $abcd$ that gives the maximal possible $e$.

Comment: You assumed $a\leq b\leq c\leq d\leq e$ but you got $e\lt d$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible that $a=b=c=d=1.$

Thus, $abcd\geq2$ and
$$e=\frac{a+b+c+d}{abcd-1}\leq5.$$
The equality occurs for $(a,b,c,d,e)=(1,1,1,2,5).$

For a proof of the last inequality we can use the following reasoning.

Let $a=1+x$, $b=1+y$, $c=1+z$ and $d=2+t$.

Thus, $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$ are non-negatives and we need to prove that:
$$5(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)(t+2)\geq5+x+y+z+t+5,$$which is obvious.